# Difference between LM335A and LM335Z?

Tags: lm335

So I'm looking to get some LM335 ICs to measure temperature, and I'm confronted by "LM335A" and "LM335Z" models (and possibly others).  Ordinarily I wouldn't think much of it, but there seems to be a reasonable price difference (the Z is about twice the price of the A).  I've tried googling and reading the LM335 datasheet, but I can't seem to figure out the difference between the two.  Or is there no practical difference?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The two models are `LM335`, and `LM335A`. The `Z` suffix indicates package type.

In this case, the `A` version has an "Uncalibrated Temperature Error" of 1°c nominal, 3°c max, while the non `A` version is 2°c nominal, 6°c max.

This is all in the datasheet, which you should read if you are thinking about implementing a circuit using this device.

The datasheet is [here](http://www.national.com/profile/snip.cgi/openDS=LM335). The specs which differentiate the two models are primarily on page two.

Manufacturers almost universally offer varying accuracy grades with temperature sensors. This is an example.

Comment: Various grades and package codes are present in virtually all ICs and can often blur together becoming near-impossible to parse...unless you consult the datasheet; usually sections like "Ordering Information".